# XCode search stops when end reached

Tags: xcode4.2

In normal situation XCode starts searching from the top of the source file, when it reaches the bottom. But in my case for some reason it stops to search and shows indicator - look at screenshot. I guess, that I have changed a setting. But I don't know how to return it to the default behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH, I found solution myself. The "wrap" should be checked: 
[image]